# Только горизонтальная прокрутка div

Tags: html

Всем привет!

Подскажите как сделать только горизонтальную прокрутку?

Я делаю:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll">
   <div style="float:left">Sect 1</div>
   <div style="float:left">Sect 2</div>
   <div style="float:left">Sect 3</div>
</div>
```

При этом внутренние секции добавляются динамически, но скролл происходит только вертикально после заполнения внешнего блока по горизонтали. А мне надо, чтобы внутренние секции располагались по горизонтали, и скроллинг внешнего блока происходил только по горизонтали.

Comment: Возможно, ширина внешнего блока жестко задана и добавляемые блоки сползают вниз, следовательно, появляется вертикальный скролл.

Answer (score 5):

Вот как это делается, господа: http://jsfiddle.net/yeo0m0dk/

**Ключевые моменты:** `display: inline-block;` внутренние элементы, и `white-space: nowrap;` родителю.

Для того чтобы между inline-block элементами не было лишнего расстояния, можно так-же добавить родителю: `font-size: 0;`.

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height:80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: yellow;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 60px;
    height:60px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо!! очень помогло! делала прокрутку для галерейки, картинки не хотели подвигаться и стоять в ряд. долго думала как сделать и чтоб красиво и чтоб работало, все гуд!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы внутренние секции располагались по горизонтали надо добавить в `style` `"display:inline;"` для каждой внутренней секции.

Comment: не помогло...

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить в style "`overflow-x:scrolll;overflow-y:hidden;max-height: высота блока;`"

Comment: не помогло тоже...

Answer (score 0):

Сделай внутренние секции в виде списка

```
 <ul>
    <li class='element'>Содержимое 1</li>
    <li class='element'>Содержимое 2</li>
    <li class='element'>Содержимое 3</li>
    <li class='element'>Содержимое 4</li>
 </ul>
```

А потом задайте в цсс для каждого .element { display: table-cell}

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```